# OSMNX not choosing shorter route

Tags: python, osmnx

I'm using OSMnx to do routing between two nodes in a graph and an obvious route is not being returned as one of the shortest.

The relevant code:

```
start = (42.73843806388065, -84.51908658324757) 
distance_max = 3163.834987247283
G = ox.graph_from_point(start, network_type="drive", dist=distance_max, simplify=False)#, truncate_by_edge=True)
G = ox.utils_graph.get_undirected(G)

lng_orig = -84.51858078986406
lat_orig = 42.73524265064318
lng_dest = -84.51910484455361
lat_dest = 42.753847179060145

orig = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, X=lng_orig, Y=lat_orig)
dest = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, X=lng_dest, Y=lat_dest)

k_routes = ox.k_shortest_paths(G, orig, dest, 30, weight="distance")

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_routes(G, list(k_routes), route_colors='r', route_linewidth=5, node_size=20)
plt.show()
```

The top 30 routes are shown in the image below, I expected a best route to be the road to the right of the long north-south road in the top half of the image. The nodes appear to be connected.

[top 30 routes shown in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCv8d.png)

Comment: Mind posting the code you used to load this road network, and the values of `orig` and `dest`? It would make the example reproducible.

Comment: @NickODell - updated, the network will be bigger than needed, but should be reproducible now.

Comment: Your starting/ending nodes might be a bit different because I am adding nodes next to those orig/dest locations between getting the graph and the routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fix

You want to use a weight of length, not distance.

```
k_routes = ox.k_shortest_paths(G, orig, dest, 30, weight="length")
```

[routes with length metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZY28.png)

#### Explanation

This problem is caused by a weird interaction between the OSMnx and networkx libraries.

If you read the [docs for `k_shortest_paths()`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.k_shortest_paths), it never mentions that you can pass `weight="distance"`. It turns out that you get the behavior you're seeing if you pass any invalid weight.

```
k_routes = ox.k_shortest_paths(G, orig, dest, 30, weight="blah")
```

If you do this, the weight value put on every graph edge becomes None. OSMnx then calls `networkx.shortest_simple_paths()`. The [docs for that function](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.shortest_simple_paths) say that if every weight is None, then the graph is treated as if every edge has unit weight:

> If None all edges are considered to have unit weight.

The kind of distance it's optimizing for here is [graph distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)). In graph distance, all of the edges between each point have distance one. A road with a curve in it has a distance equal to the number of points used to represent the curve. A long straight road has a distance of one.

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I switched the weight away from travel_time at some point (I'm doing bicycle routing) and didn't get an error passing in distance so assumed it was working as expected. Thanks for the quick work and explanation!