# How is the shortest path computed with Osmnx and NetworkX?

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

When trying to compute the shortest path with various methods, I don't get the same result (which you could expect) but I can't tell how each one is working...

For instance, when working with the French city Annecy here are the results when applying Dijkstra algorithm from `NetworkX` or from `OSMnx`

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx


Cities = ['Annecy, France','Epagny Metz-Tessy, France']
graph_city = ox.graph_from_place(Cities, network_type='drive', simplify=True, truncate_by_edge=False, clean_periphery =True)
graph_city = ox.project_graph(graph_city)
graph_city = ox.consolidate_intersections(graph_city, rebuild_graph=True, tolerance=15, dead_ends=True)


graph_city = ox.add_edge_speeds(graph_city)
graph_city = ox.add_edge_travel_times(graph_city)


DEP_node = 530
ARR_node  = 549


path_NX = nx.dijkstra_path(graph_city, DEP_node, ARR_node)
path_OX_L = ox.shortest_path(graph_city, DEP_node, ARR_node, weight='length')
path_OX_T = ox.shortest_path(graph_city, DEP_node, ARR_node, weight='time')

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_routes(graph_city, [path_NX,path_OX_L,path_OX_T], route_colors=['r','g','y'], route_linewidth=4,node_size=1, figsize=(7,7), bgcolor='#FFFFFF', node_color='#111111')
```

Then to access the time or the length of each path, I apply those lines :

```
Time = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(graph_city,path, 'travel_time')))
Length = int(sum(ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(graph_city, path, 'length')))
```

And here are my results :

```
             path_NX         path_OX_L          path_OX_T
TIME           238              211                238
LENGTH        2136             1959               2136
```

**So it appears that path_OX_L (using `OSMnx` to compute the shortest path with the length) is not only the shortest in length but also the quicker. Then, what is the aim of having a path that should be quicker :`path_OX_T` which clearly is not ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path_OX_T = ox.shortest_path(graph_city, DEP_node, ARR_node, weight='time')
```

The attribute `time` does not exist, and osmnx therefore minimizes graph distance. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74944181/osmnx-not-choosing-shorter-route/74944707#74944707).

Change it to this:

```
path_OX_T = ox.shortest_path(graph_city, DEP_node, ARR_node, weight='travel_time')
```

Comment: Perfect! So if my understanding is correct, ```nx.dijkstra_path()``` considers the graph with unit weight for each edge, resulting in the path with the fewer edges but not the quickest (or shortest) one. Am I correct?

Comment: @AlistairLucet That's correct.